# HTML5 video element "seeked" event

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

There are two events for seek in HTML video player.

1. Seeking : Seek operation began
2. Seeked : seek operation completed

For every corresponding seeking event we have seeked event.
But In my project for some of seeking event, we are not getting the seeked event.

Here my question are:

1. Why is it happening so that we are getting seeked event ?
2. Is it possible that media player doesn't capture all events?

Comment: Having a [mcve] would help us help you here. What browser(s) are you experiencing this with? How was the seeking performed (user interaction, script)? To what value was it set? What duration is the media resource?

Comment: There are 1% cases where are not getting this issue. It is not browser specific. for every browser behavior is same.  Out of these 1% case, 60% are user actions to perform seek and rest are change in current position using code.
we are just logging event there I found that  we dont have seeked event corresponding seeking event. We dont reproducing steps.

Comment: I working on website where I am trying to host a video from there I got these number.
I totally get your point that we can couple of seeking we are seeking before previous seek event is completed. But my question is bit different . we just have seeking after which we dont have seeked or seeking event . but we find that video is playing. So is it possible media player has missed that event.

Answer (score 0):

If a second seeking event occurs before the first seek operation is over, you will have only the last *seeked* event.

This may happen relatively easily with big video files e.g if the whole data is not prefetched, or when the user scrubs through the timeline controls.

```js
let seeking = false;
vid.onseeking = e => {
  if (seeking) {
    // if we enter here it means we had a seeking event
    // that hasn't been matched by a seeked one
    console.log("already seeking");
  }
  seeking = true;
};
vid.onseeked = e => {
  seeking = false;
};

vid.play().then(() => {
  vid.currentTime = 10;
  vid.currentTime = 15;
});
```

```css
video {
  height: 150px
}
```

```html
<video controls id=vid src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm muted></video>
```

Comment: I working on website where I am trying to host a video from there I got these number. I totally get your point that we can couple of seeking we are seeking before previous seek event is completed. But my question is bit different . we just have seeking after which we dont have seeked or seeking event . but we find that video is playing. So is it possible media player has missed that event

Comment: Not seeing your code it's impossible to understand your situation, sorry. But anyway, you shouldn't expect each seeking event to map to a seeked one.

Comment: I am just logging the events .
vid.onseeked = function() {
console.log("Seek operation completed! "+ vid.readyState)
};

vid.onseeking = function() {
console.log("Seek operation began! "+ vid.readyState)
};

Comment: From logs I found that we have "seeking" event and after that only "progress" event . 
we dont have seeked event for seeking event.